# Redirect from 1 site to another bypassing the login page

Tags: c#, vb.net, single-sign-on, session-cookies, session-state

I have to websites - A (written in C# using ASP.NET Web Forms) and B (written in VB using ASP.NET MVC4). Both websites are on different domains, require logging into and do not share the same database. I need to make sure that the users of website A could get access to website B without the need to authenticate on website B.

My proposed solution may not be what you would call a "best practice". I decided to set up a fictitious user on website B, whose credentials and permissions would be used by the users of website A (without their knowledge - hence bypassing the Login Page on website B).

I have the following API request in the code of website A:

```
HttpWebRequest post = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://siteB/api/WebsiteA/Authenticate/");
post.Method="POST";
post.KeepAlive = true;
string postData = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&hash=" + hash + "&timestamp=" + timestamp + "&returnUrl=" + returnUrl;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
post.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
post.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = post.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = post.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseFromServer);
if (d.First().Value == "ok")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_AU);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_UD);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_UL);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);        
}
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

On website B I have the following Handler:

```
Public Class WebsiteAController
Inherits ApiController

<HttpPost()> _
Public Function Authenticate(params As API_AuthModel) As HttpResponseMessage
    Try
        Dim Result As New API_JSONResult

        ' Authenticate the message
        Dim Auth As New API_Auth
        If Auth.AuthenticateMessage(params.Hash, params.Timestamp, params.Email) Then
            ' If authentication is successful
            If Membership.ValidateUser(params.Email, params.Password) Then
                Result.status = "ok"
                Result.message = SystemAuth.GenerateNewToken() 'token
            Else
                Result.status = "invalid"
                Result.message = "Invalid authentication credentials"
            End If
        Else
            Result.status = "error"
            Result.message = "Invalid message"
        End If

        ' Ensure the result is returned as JSON without further serialisation as this has been done already
        Dim ResponseMsg = New HttpResponseMessage()
        ResponseMsg = ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Result)
        ResponseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")

        Return ResponseMsg

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    End Try
End Function
```

Unfortunately I have come to understand that this is not working. The main problem being that after my users authenticate successfully, they are not "remembered" as authenticated on website B. And the cookies I add to the response from website A do not seem to help either. I get redirected to the login page on website B. Am I doing something majorly wrong here? People have vaguely mentioned to me that API is stateless, and that I need to pass the Session_ID. If that is the case, how could I get the Session_Id and pass it between the two websites?

If you have any better suggestions/criticism please do share. I am very very new to API and I have spent my last 3 weeks attempting different solutions. It is very likely that I have understood how API works all wrong.

Comment: You could look at how OpenID does it. It send the information with a secret password (you should encrypt) and then receive a token. When you switch site, you could send that token in the querystring. Using the token you could authenticate on the other side and then delete the token. Cookies are not shared between sites.

Comment: Thank you **the_lotus** for your advice. I struggled to find my way around OpenID (perhaps I need to spend longer reading about it), although I see how it could be helpful to me on this occasion. 

Please, excuse me, if my question seems silly, but if I chose to use tokens, would I still be using the above API call and Handler? My understanding is that I still need to write a request and authenticate the user prior to returning an authentication token to website A. Is that correct?